# What geologic features could this video game environment be modeled from, and how do they form?

Tags: structural-geology

I have been playing this game for a while and I like the city's setting. It seem to be placed on a rock platform, or a mesa maybe, connected to the mainland on the bottom-left. It also has some connection in the top left and middle right.

I would like to know what this structure is called so I can find some real-life such occurrences in order to draw some fan-art for this game.

I would also like to know, if possible, what sort of parameters does nature require to make such an effect. What kind of climate, rock combinations, that sort of thing.

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ijMaNGAolQI/maxresdefault.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flatland with occasional huge rocks and abundant rivers and lakes. One possibility might be a plain that experienced glaciation, bringing in the erratic rocks and carving the landscape.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the landscape, it almost appears to be a highland, with steep valleys carved by a misty river - which suggests possible waterfalls.  I am reminded of Victoria Falls, on the border of Zimbabwe and Zambia (part of the landscape pictured below)

[image]

[Image source](http://nature-nest.com/some-of-the-most-beautiful-waterfalls-on-earth/)

The geological processes that formed these features is summarised in the webpage [The Geology of Victoria Falls](http://vicfalls.zimbabwe.co.za/Climate,_Geology,_Flora-travel/explore-victoria-falls-geology.html) as a series of tectonic and erosional activity over an ancient basaltic bedrock, forming a series of near parallel gorges (shown below and from the webpage linked before).

[image]

Comment: Could this spawn a mesa-like top? By this I mean a disk-like surface topside. What such size would this take, on average?

Comment: @Discipol Potentially yes, but that would depend on many factors - such as erosion rate, position of tectonic features, erosional and tectonic history..

Comment: So what size could such a formation take? Also what temperature / humidity could you find at those altitudes. Also what altitudes does this occur? :D